# Cannot start Wubi 11.10 without "nomodeset"

Tags: wubi, intel-graphics, backlight

I am a bit of a Linux noob, so help me out a bit.

I installed Ubuntu 11.10 in Wubi on my Acer Aspire 5734z laptop ([specs][1])
and when i boot, i have to use `nomodeset` by pressing **e** at bootup, or the backlight won't work.

I am sure I need to do something with ACPI, but am not sure how. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this fix](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=10740136&postcount=3):
In the grub menu, press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the line starting with `linux /boot/...`. Add the following at the end: `acpi_osi=Linux`. 
Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to boot and press the brightness up key while starting.

Then edit the file /etc/rc.local (`gksu gedit /etc/rc.local`) and add before exit 0:

`setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=00`

Edit /etc/default/grub (`gksu gedit /etc/default/grub`), edit the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT = "quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"`

Update grub with:
`sudo update-grub`

Refer to [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/826386) for more info.